# spark gcp dataproc dependency error with guava

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, guava, google-cloud-dataproc

Our project uses gradle and scala to build spark app, but I've added gcp kms library and now when this runs on dataproc it errors with missing guava method:

```
java.lang.noSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument
```

I followed the recommendations on the following guide to shade the google libraries:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/managing-java-dependencies-apache-spark-applications-cloud-dataproc

My shadowJar definition in gradle build:

```
shadowJar {
  zip64 true
  relocate 'com.google', 'shadow.com.google'
  relocate 'com.google.protobuf', 'shadow.com.google.protobuf'
  relocate 'google.cloud', 'shadow.google.cloud'
  exclude 'META-INF/**'
  exclude "LICENSE*"
  mergeServiceFiles()
  archiveFileName = "myjar"
}
```

When running `java tf` on compiled fat jar this shows the guava classes including checkArgument being relocated under `shadow`.

But it still errors when runnin dataproc spark submit and it still seems to choose the old versions from hadoop at runtime. Below is the stack trace, starting from my KmsSymettric class which is using gcp kms decrypt:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: shadow.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:629)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:637)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:567)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:742)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:737)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:593)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:589)
    at shadow.com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.<init>(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at shadow.com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:221)
    at shadow.com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:194)
    at shadow.com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:186)
    at shadow.com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:155)
    at shadow.com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.create(GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.java:370)
    at shadow.com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.createStub(KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.java:333)
    at shadow.com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.<init>(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:155)
    at shadow.com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:136)
    at shadow.com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:127)
    at mycompany.my.class.path.KmsSymmetric.decrypt(KmsSymmetric.scala:31)
```

My dataproc submit is:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster=${CLUSTER_NAME} \
--project ${PROJECT_ID} \
--region=${REGION} \
--jars=gs://${APP_BUCKET}/${JAR} \
--class=${CLASS} \
--app args --arg1 val1 etc
```

I'm using dataproc image version 1.4

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please share your spark local client library version?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? if yes could you please share what you did?